# How to select a different theme/style for CodeRay syntax highlighting Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, coderay

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to select a different theme/style for syntax highlighting of Ruby code using the CodeRay gem, the default is OK but i wonder if there's anything else on offer? i can't seem to find them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you generate your own coderay.css file. Coderay doesn't have "themes".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[CodeRay stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157105/coderay-stylesheet/11236224#11236224)

And then:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  doc.search("//pre//code[@class]").each do |pre|
    tokens = CodeRay.scan(pre.text, pre[:class])
    pre.replace tokens.div(:css => :class)
  end
```

The trick is to render your tokens with a CSS class.