# CodeRay stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coderay

```
require 'coderay'
puts CodeRay.scan('puts "Hello, world!"', :ruby).page
```

This code will print full HTML page with CSS(classes).

I may print only colored code using `CodeRay.scan('puts "Hello, world!"', :ruby).div`
How can I print only CSS part?

There is `stylesheet` method in `CodeRay::Encoders::HTML::Output`, but how can I call it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `coderay` command installed along with the CodeRay gem can print out a stylesheet for you.

```
$ coderay stylesheet > coderay.css
```

Or you could do something with it in code maybe.

```
require 'coderay'

style = CodeRay::Encoders[:html]::CSS.new(:default).stylesheet
puts style
```